# Remove label text if it already exists

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I'm looking to add a feature to a winforms application that allows the employee to sign in with a badge that begins with EMP (for this example). I have four labels for a maximum of four employees. With the code below, if Employee 1 (label one) signs out and then Employee 4 tries to sign out, Employee 4 fills the spot of Employee 1 since its going in order. I'm sure there is an easy way to do this without using all these if statements I'm just having some trouble. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
if (EmployeeOneLabel.Text == "" && ScanEntryTextBox.Text.Contains(EmployeePrefix)) 
    {
        EmployeeOneLabel.Text = ScanEntryTextBox.Text;
        EmployeeOneSaved = EmployeeOneLabel.Text;
        ScanEntryTextBox.Text = "";
    } else if(ScanEntryTextBox.Text == EmployeeOneSaved)
    {   
        EmployeeOneLabel.Text = "";
        ScanEntryTextBox.Text = "";
    }
    if (EmployeeTwoLabel.Text == "" && ScanEntryTextBox.Text.Contains(EmployeePrefix))
    {
        EmployeeTwoLabel.Text = ScanEntryTextBox.Text;
        EmployeeTwoSaved = EmployeeTwoLabel.Text;
        ScanEntryTextBox.Text = "";
    } else if (ScanEntryTextBox.Text == EmployeeTwoSaved)
    {   
        EmployeeTwoLabel.Text = "";
        ScanEntryTextBox.Text = "";
    }
    if (EmployeeThreeLabel.Text == "" && ScanEntryTextBox.Text.Contains(EmployeePrefix))
    {
        EmployeeThreeLabel.Text = ScanEntryTextBox.Text;
        EmployeeThreeSaved = EmployeeThreeLabel.Text;
        ScanEntryTextBox.Text = "";
    } else if (ScanEntryTextBox.Text == EmployeeThreeSaved)
    {
        EmployeeThreeLabel.Text = "";
        ScanEntryTextBox.Text = "";
    }
    if (EmployeeFourLabel.Text == "" && ScanEntryTextBox.Text.Contains(EmployeePrefix))
    {
        EmployeeFourLabel.Text = ScanEntryTextBox.Text;
        EmployeeFourSaved = EmployeeFourLabel.Text;
        ScanEntryTextBox.Text = "";
    } else if (ScanEntryTextBox.Text == EmployeeFourSaved)
    {
        EmployeeFourLabel.Text = "";
        ScanEntryTextBox.Text = "";
    }
```

New updated code based on @PaulF suggestions.

```
private string EmployeePrefix = "EMP";
List<string> listEmployee = new List<string>();
public TimeTrack()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
private void EnterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label[] LabelEmployee = { EmployeeOneLabel, EmployeeTwoLabel, EmployeeThreeLabel, EmployeeFourLabel };
    if (ScanEntryTextBox.Text.Contains(EmployeePrefix))
    {
        if (listEmployee.Contains(ScanEntryTextBox.Text))
        {
            listEmployee.Remove(ScanEntryTextBox.Text);
            ScanEntryTextBox.Text = "";
        } else
        {
            listEmployee.Add(ScanEntryTextBox.Text);
            ScanEntryTextBox.Text = "";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < LabelEmployee.Length; i++)
        {
            LabelEmployee[i].Text = listEmployee.ElementAtOrDefault(i) ?? "";
            ScanEntryTextBox.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Moving label text up]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a list of strings.

When you get a valid employee badge - check if it is in the list & remove it if it is otherwise add it to the end of the list.

Then update the labels with the new list contents.

Something like :

```
List<string> listEmployee = new List<string>();

...
...

if (ScanEntryTextBox.Text.Contains(EmployeePrefix) && (listEmployee.Count < 4))
{
  if (listEmployee.Contains(ScanEntryTextBox.Text))
    listEmployee.Remove(ScanEntryTextBox.Text);
  else
    listEmployee.Add(ScanEntryTextBox.Text);
  EmployeeOneLabel.Text = listEmployee.ElementAtOrDefault(0) ?? "";
  EmployeeTwoLabel.Text = listEmployee.ElementAtOrDefault(1) ?? "";
  EmployeeThreeLabel.Text = listEmployee.ElementAtOrDefault(2) ?? "";
  EmployeeFourLabel.Text = listEmployee.ElementAtOrDefault(3) ?? "";
}
```

You could probably create an array of labels & use a for loop for the update of the labels.

```
Label [] labelEmployee = {EmployeeOneLabel, EmployeeTwoLabel, EmployeeThreeLabel, EmployeeFourLabel};
List<string> listEmployee = new List<string>();

...
...

if (ScanEntryTextBox.Text.Contains(EmployeePrefix) && (listEmployee.Count < labelEmployee.Length))
{
  if (listEmployee.Contains(ScanEntryTextBox.Text))
    listEmployee.Remove(ScanEntryTextBox.Text);
  else
    listEmployee.Add(ScanEntryTextBox.Text);
  for (int i = 0; i < labelEmployee.Length; i++)
    labelEmployee[i].Text = listEmployee.ElementAtOrDefault(i) ?? "";
}
```

Comment: This is working with the suggestions you have made, however it is moving the label up one when it removes it. Is there away for it leave the labels in place? I have uploaded a GIF to the main post. 

I removed the > count < 4 because would not run if all 4 labels were filled up (to start removing).

Comment: Well done, you spotted my deliberate mistake (ok I missed it) - you can add limit of 4 restriction to the else before adding. The way I read your original question I thought you wanted the signed in employees to move up if an earlier one signed out - if that is not the case then you can just the array of labels - when the employee signs in, just search the array of labels to see if he is signed in, if so clear the array, if not search the array again for the first blank label. (You could optimise that by saving the position of the first blank label as you are looking to see if he is signed in)